# DBCombobox salvando indice

Tags: delphi

Eu sou novato em Delphi e estou fazendo um `form` onde todas as entradas são `DBLookup`. Necessito de um `Combobox` para selecionar se a pessoa possui pais conhecidos ou não. Exemplo:

- 0 - Possui pais,
- 1 - Não possui.

Eu consigo colocar isto no `DBCombobox` mas como faço para atualizar o banco com `0` ou `1`? O campo é do tipo `varchar`. Com o `DBLookupCombobox` eu teria que obter os dados de um `sql`, o que não vem ao caso por serem apenas duas informações.

Comment: qual versão do delphi você usa?

Answer (score 1):

O componente `ComboBox` cria um índice para cada item que você inclui na lista. Neste caso, se você criar na ordem que apresentou em sua pergunta, os índices ficariam *0 = "Possui Pais"* e *1 = "Não possui"*. Depois disso é só chamar a propriedade `ItemIndex` do `ComboBox` para gravar no banco de dados a opção selecionada pelo usuário, conforme o exemplo abaixo:

```
query.edit;    // edita o registro
query.fieldbyname('CampoDaTabela').AsString := IntToStr(ComboBox.ItemIndex); 
query.post;   // salva o registro
```

Comment: Se o campo for `Integer` você usa `AsInteger` no lugar de `AsString` que ficaria assim: `query.fieldbyname('CampoDaTabela').AsInteger := ComboBox.ItemIndex;`

Answer (score 0):

a forma mais correta seria clicando em um botão após todas as alterações ou o cadastro estar realizado onde você pode realizar da seguinte forma.

```
query.append;  // inclui um novo registro no banco de dados
query.edit;    // edita o registro
query.fieldbyname('CampoDaTabela').value := valor do edit, combo, etc; 
query.post;   // salva o registro
```

ou da forma nao muito correta que seria ao sair do campo.

para realizar dessa forma no evento onExit da combo coloque o mesmo procedimento acima, validando se é inclusão ou alteração, para o determinado campo.